# Including own font by HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts

I can add custom type by google fonts, and by including directly from server(here I use css). How can I includ directly fonts from server by only HTML? I need to include this by HTML because the last version of Internet Explorer can't load fonts by CSS. When I use just google fonts IE don't display my special polish characters.

**Google fonts**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
src: url(fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot);
src: local('Open Sans'), url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format("truetype")
```

}

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: You cannot include fonts via *html only* - if you check the contents of the file you linked from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans you'll see it's a css snippet including the font. Using the generator suggested by BenM will create a css snippet for you that includes IE support.

Comment: I used this site but, this don't solve my problem x)

Comment: Have you tried different options for "script" at google fonts? Like, say http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin-ext - read more at https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Subsets

Comment: The question is based on a misunderstanding. The comment by @xec solves the real problem, but I’m afraid it’s not the answer to the question asked…

Answer (score 1):

*How can I includ directly fonts from server by only HTML?* <-- Can't get this quietly than too..

You should declare multiple fonts as a fallback, for example

```
p {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
}
```

This way, if the *`Open Sans`* fails to load, it will look for *`Arial`*

Comment: @xec Yes, I guess Arial covers pretty much

Comment: *"When I use just google fonts IE don't display my special polish characters."* - I took this to mean that the font gets loaded, but special glyphs don't work. Including a fallback font won't help with that.

Comment: Mr.Alien is right, You always need a back-up as you can't expect everyone to be using the same browser

Comment: @Gorthard Use a font family which supports those special glyphs, don't use generalized font family for all